# alpineJS controlled form submits original value instead of x-model sync one

Tags: forms, preventdefault, alpine.js

I have an comment section with edit in place functionality. It is a modified version of https://codepen.io/brbcoding-the-selector/pen/yLNvexO with backend submission. On the front end, everything seems to work. The problem comes when I submit the info to the back end. The original comment content instead of the edited one is submitted. Here you can see a gif [original submission insteado of new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Gzf.gif)

The text area holding the content is synched with Alpine to a variable via x-model directive. The problem is that, even though I update this variable (I see it updated while console logging), the original value is submitted.
To submit, I prevent original form behaviour and call a method, in which I update the variables and then submit the form.
Here is my form:

```
        <label x-show=isEditing class="flex flex-col">
            <div class="flex mb-4">
                <form @submit.prevent="save" method="POST" action="{{ $comment->path()}}" class="w-full">
                    @method('PATCH')
                    @csrf
                    <textarea 
                        type="text"
                        x-ref="textInput"
                        class="w-full p-2 border"
                        x-model="newText"
                        @keydown.enter="save"
                        @keydown.escape="cancel"
                    ></textarea>
                    <button type="button" class="p-2 ml-2" title="Cancel" @click="cancel">ⓧ</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="p-2 ml-2" title="Save">✅</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <small class="text-xs">→ hit Enter to save</small>
            <small class="text-xs">→ hit Esc to cancel</small>
          </label>
```

And here is my alpine object, which contains "save" function that actually submits the form:

```
        x-data="{
            origText: '{{ $comment->content }}',
            newText: null,
            isEditing: false,
            edit: function() {
               this.isEditing = true;
            },
            focus: function() {
                const textInput = this.$refs.textInput;
                textInput.focus();
                //textInput.select();                 
             },
             save: function() {
                this.origText = this.newText;
                this.isEditing = false;
                console.log(this.origText);
                console.log(this.newText);
                console.log(event.target);
                event.target.submit();
             },
             cancel: function() {
                this.newText = this.origText;
                this.isEditing = false;
             },
        }" 
        x-init="newText = origText"
```

I tried using $ticks magic of alpine and also using simple delays, but no success. It seems it is not a timing problem. Thanks

Comment: The textarea does not have a `name` attribute, so the submitted form will be empty. Could you try it with a correct `name`?

Comment: @dauros, Thanks a lot. This was the biggest own facepalm for a very long time.